# Error trying to run seeds: Knex: Timeout acquiring a connection. The pool is probably full

Tags: javascript, node.js, knex.js

I'm getting this error everytime i run `yarn knex seed:run`:

> Error while executing "/home/user/path-to-the-file/my-seed.js" seed: Knex: Timeout acquiring a connection. The pool is probably full. Are you missing a .transacting(trx) call?

The problem is that i send the project for other people and they can run it normally, i already tried all answers about it of the internet, i don't know what to do anymore.

My database config:

```
const config = Object.freeze({
  client: 'pg',
  pool: {
    min: 0,
    max: 5,
    idleTimeoutMillis: 30000,
    createTimeoutMillis: 3000,
    acquireTimeoutMillis: 30000,
    reapIntervalMillis: 1000,
    createRetryIntervalMillis: 100,
    propagateCreateError: false
  },
  connection: Object.freeze({
    ...database
  })
})
```

- Knex version: "^0.95.8"
- pg version: "^8.7.1"
- Yarn version: 1.22.11
- Node version: 14.17.4

I already tried to downgrade pg and node, it didnt work, nothing works.

There is a issue on **Knex** repository saying that upgrading to latest `pg` solves it, but it didnt work too: https://github.com/knex/knex/issues/2820

Can someone help me?

Comment: Your seeds has bugs. No-one can help you unless you show the breaking code. Try to remove reduce the size of example code to a part that is actually causing the failure.

Comment: What kind of bug it could be? Why it just dont show me the real error instead throwing this generic error.

Comment: It is kind of error where you are requesting too many connections in parallel from knex and it runs out of connections to give you. Knex doesn't know any better either what you are doing with those connections. You can monitor what kind of queries/transactions knex is running for example by setting `DEBUG=knex:*` environment variable before running seeds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy way to create this error is doing this:

```
const rows = [];
for (let i =  0; i < 10000; i++) {
  rows.push({ name : `foo  ${i}` });
}
await Promise.all(rows.map(data => knex('user').insert(data)));
```

There are infinite ways how to run out of connections, but most usual cases are opening too many concurrent transactions or running huge amount of parallel queries.

Best way to find out the reason why it happen is to remove parts of the problematic code until the error doesn't occur anymore and then investigate why that reduced test case fails.

One good way to see what knex is doing internally is to set `DEBUG=knex:*` environment variable, before running the code so that knex outputs information about queries, transactions and pool connections while code executes.

Comment: Yes, thats what happened, i just reduced the value of a variable that inserted too many rows and my seeds started to run normally, i still dont get it, is it because of my pc performance or the code bad written? Because on my coworkers the seeds runs normally, but to me this always throws an error.

Comment: Code is written badly, there is no reason why that should happen even if the PC performance is not the best. Also if DB is not ran locally the internet connection can make the problem to appear just on your setup.

Answer (score 0):

faced similar issued, bumped pg to 8.7.1 and it worked

also  node to 16.3.1 and knex to 0.95.11

Comment: I tried everything, downgrade, upgrade pg, node, anything, only way to solve was upgrade my PC from HD to SSD. This is a code issue, the company it was working had this seeds and i had to run it, but i was bad written not considering performance so probably the hardware couldn't handle it.

Comment: are you using objection or typeorm or anyother orm.?

Comment: No ORM were being used